# Regular expression to find smallest possible match

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using a JavaScript regular expression `/(<mos>[\s\S]*?<\/mos>)/g` to find XML blocks in a log file that looks roughly like this:

```
Entry 1: <mos>...</mos>
Entry 2: <mos>...</mos>
```

However, sometimes the logging process encounters an error and doesn't finish writing an entry to the file, in which case it looks like this:

```
Entry 1: <mos>Error!
Entry 2: <mos>...</mos>
```

When this happens the regular expression matches everything from the opening `<mos>` tag in entry 1 to the closing `</mos>` tag in entry 2 which causes problems when processing the XML later.

It seems that somehow matching the closing tags first and then looking back for their corresponding opening tags would avoid this, but I don't know how to do this or if it is possible with regular expressions.

---

**Clarification**: The `...` in the blocks delimited by the start and end tags can include newlines.

Comment: Why would you match on `[\s\S]*` when what you want is "everything up to either `<` or `\n`"?

Comment: "You can't parse [X]HTML with regex" ..or XML for that matter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans The `...` in the entries can span multiple lines. I've updated my question to include that.

Comment: @gion_13 It's not XML, but a log file containing XML (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261561/please-stop-linking-to-the-zalgo-anti-cthulhu-regex-rant) `;)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one should suit your needs:

```
<mos>((?:[\s\S](?!<mos>))+?)</mos>
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Visualization by [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/_u4568NeE6iAxioj)

Demo on [RegExr](http://www.regexr.com/39jaf)

---

Don't forget to escape the slashes if using a JS regex literal.